# What is DEFAULT_CC in function declaration?

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor

I'm relatively new to **C**, and am curious what this syntax means in a function declaration:

```
int DEFAULT_CC foo(void)
```

where DEFAULT_CC is probably defined somewhere else as:

```
#define DEFAULT_CC      "something"
```

(I realized the previous example I had up had to do with something completely irrelevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More likely calling convention.  A calling convention defines exactly how values are passed to and returned from a function.  Typical values might be `cdecl` or `stdcall`. For a comprehensive explanation of x86 conventions, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

```
int "cc" foo(void)
```

wouldn't compile.

Comment: For example:
http://www.sfr-fresh.com/linux/misc/xrdp-0.4.1.tar.gz:a/xrdp-0.4.1/common/arch.h

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I got the second line of code (with the "cc") from something I googled, and not the original project, so that probably was something different someone was using the same name for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're messing up C code with makefile notation, because DEFAULT_CC is the standard makefile variable for setting default C compiler.

Comment: In what make?  In [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/make/Catalogue-of-Rules.html), that's `CC`.

Comment: Actually, found it in imake and in mkdep sources. I was wrong stating it as standard makefile variable. Anyway it's very likely that #define DEFAULT_CC      "cc" is taken from sources of make related tool.